# Change constant in tensoflow session while looping

Tags: tensorflow

How can I change the tensorflow constant inside session ***for loop***.
I am a learner and I am wondering how to update it in for loop

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

looperCount = 10

data = np.random.randint(2, size=looperCount)
x = tf.constant(data, name='x')

y = tf.Variable((5 * (x * x)) - (3 * x) + 15, name="y")
model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(looperCount):
        sess.run(model)
        data = np.random.randint(2, size=looperCount)
        x = tf.constant(data, name='x')
        avg = np.average(sess.run(y))
        print "avg - {}, sess - {}".format(avg, sess.run(y))
```

---

Updated working code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

looperCount = 10

x = tf.placeholder("float", looperCount)
y = (5 * (x * x)) - (3 * x) + 15

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(looperCount):
        data = np.random.randint(10, size=looperCount)
        result_y = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: data})
        avg = np.average(result_y)
        print "avg - {:10} valy - {:10}".format("{:.2f}".format(avg), result_y)
```

Answer (score 10):

In TensorFlow, "constant" means exactly that: once you set it, you can't change it. To change the value that your TensorFlow program uses in the loop, you have two main choices: (1) using a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) to feed in a value, or (2) using a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) to store the value between steps, and [`tf.Variable.assign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.assign) to update it.

Option 1 is much easier. Here's an example of how you could use it to implement your program using a placeholder:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

looperCount = 10

data = np.random.randint(2, size=looperCount)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[2], name="x")

y = tf.Variable((5 * (x * x)) - (3 * x) + 15, name="y")
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)      
    for i in range(looperCount):
        data = np.random.randint(2, size=looperCount)
        avg = np.average(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: data}))
        print "avg - {}, sess - {}".format(avg, sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: data}))
```

Comment: this means that we no longer can change values of the tensors in a .pb file using `tf.Assign`? Full question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961959/tf-assign-to-a-protocol-buffer-frozen-model-in-tensorflow

Comment: Bit rot has set in on your links. They're all giving 404s.